# How to get an excel file from web and store it in an azure blob storage

Tags: azure, blob, azure-data-factory

I have an ADF pipeline that process an excel file in azure blob storage. The excel file is actually downloaded from
[Here](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/1002437/UK_stats_on_waste_dataset_July_2021_accessible_rev_v4.xlsx) and then manually uploaded on the azure blob storage.
I want to automate this process of downloading the excel from the link and then load it in the azure blob storage. Is there any way to do it using ADF or any other Azure Service

Comment: Great. What’s your question? See [ask]

Comment: Please edit your question and include what you have tried so far and the issues you're running into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The non-code option that comes to mind is Logic apps.
Your Logic apps will look this. After the trigger you will need a HTTP action followed by a copy blob to copy that content into your storage account.

[image]

Your Create blob step will look like this. The blob content will be the response body of the previous http request. [image]

You can have this scheduled at a regular interval.

Comment: What to specify in Blob Content?  In Create Blob i see this option to enter Blob Content

Comment: You need to use the response body of the previous http request. See my revised answer for the screen shot.

Comment: This worked. @anupam chand. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Great, Kindly mark my answer as the correct answer so this question can be closed.